# iOS: Getting Facebook's user data with Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm using parse to register users from facebook in my iOS app. This is the code I have in my log in button:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

After the user clicks it, the facebook app or safari opens up. After the user enters the email and password, it tells them that the app will see their public profile, email, friends.

Everything seems to work fine until this point. The problem comes when retrieving the user info from Parse:

```
<PFUser: 0x7fcd3ae5cae0, objectId: irrEruRILF, localId: (null)> {
username = LeFJc8ErtMLHqLmsonfNXq8Ck;
}
```

As you can see it gives me "username = LeFJc8ErtMLHqLmsonfNXq8Ck" but it doesn't have any profile information or email address... What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by opening the session with permissions first

```
FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: {
        (session:FBSession!, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError!) in

    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], block: { user, error in

       FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({connection, result, error in

       // Then I access the user data like this:
       var loginResults = result as! NSDictionary
       var facebookID = loginResults["id"] as! String
       var firstName = loginResults["first_name"] as! String
       ....
       })

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

`PFUser` is not equivalent to the Facebook user. You need to query the Graph API to retrieve data from Facebook.

Try calling this after logging in:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // handle response
}];
```

[Source](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook)